# Array resets with every keyup

Tags: javascript, arrays, addeventlistener

More specifically, what I am wanting to do is - with each hit of the enter key, the user is presented a famous quote (my switch/cases). Once they have toggled through the list (finished off the array), they will have the option to do it again (hit the ‘yes’ button). Once the yes button is pressed, the user toggles through the array again until its end is reached. (Then they have the option to do it all again, if desired). The problem occurs when I wrap the code in a function to make a call to that function with a button click. I can’t seem to recreate the process of toggling through my entire array to the finish. As mentioned, what is happening is that the array is created again and again with each hit of the enter key.  Any thoughts?

```
<body>
    <p id='show'>When enter button pressed, <br>random case selections are<br>shown here until array emptied.</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">When clicking this button, I am wanting<br>the same response from the function call,<br>
        but my event listener keeps resetting my array. How to prevent that? </button>
    <script>
        myFunction();

        function myFunction() {
            var casesDrawn = [0, 1, 2];
            document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13 && casesDrawn.length > 0) {
                    randSelect();
                }

                function randSelect() {
                    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * casesDrawn.length);
                    var num = casesDrawn[randNum];
                    casesDrawn.splice(randNum, 1);

                    switch (num) {
                        case 0:
                            document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = 'case 1 selected';
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = 'case 2 selected';
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = 'case 3 selected';
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you call `myFunction()` when the button is clicked, this line executes:

```
    var casesDrawn = [0, 1, 2];
```

So you actually create a new array and attach a new click listener. What you actually seem to want is to create a global variable `caseDrawn` and a global `randSelect` function:

```
 var casesDrawn = [0, 1, 2];

 function randSelect() { /*...*/ }

 // Attach keyup listener
 document.body.addEventListener( 'keyup', function (e) {
        if ( e.keyCode == 13 && casesDrawn.length > 0) {
            randSelect();
        }
 });

 // Attach button listener

  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", randSelect);
```

then `randSelect()` gets called on keypress and button click.